# Using glm::vec2 with std::set

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I'm trying to make an `std::set<glm::vec2>` like the following:

```
std::set<glm::vec2> playerChunkSet;
```

but it refuses to compile with the following error:

```
Error   C2678   binary '<': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const _Ty' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

I have had an issue like this with `std::map<glm::vec2>` before, but including `<glm/gtx/hash.hpp>` fixed it, I tried with sets but it didn't work, any idea on how can I fix it ?

Comment: Please care about the tags. [tag:glm] (generalized linear models) != [tag:glm-math] (GLM - OpenGL Mathematics). Note that you can click on a tag to see what it is about.

Answer (score 0):

`std::set` uses `operator<` to sort its elements. [`glm::vec2` does not have an `operator<`](https://openframeworks.cc///documentation/glm/glm::vec2/)

That [hash.hpp file you referenced](https://github.com/g-truc/glm/blob/master/glm/gtx/hash.hpp#L58) defines `hash` for `vec2`, so you should be able to include that and use `std::unordered_set<glm::vec2>`